# Помогите. Перевод названия месяца с английского на украинский: где ошибка?

Tags: дата, php

```
<?php
function normal_date($date){
    $month=array(
    'January'=>"Січня",'February'=>"Лютого",'March'=>"Березня",
    'April'=>"Квітня",'May'=>"Травня",'June'=>"Червня",
    'July'=>"Липня",'August'=>"Серпня",'September'=>"Вересня",
    'October'=>"Жовтня",'November'=>"Листопада",'December'=>"Грудня");
    $a=$month[date("F", strtotime($date))];
    $b=date("j",$date);
    $c=date("Y", strtotime($date));
    return $b.' '.$a." ".$c;}
}
function get_news(){
    $con = mysql_connect("localhost","admin","123");
    if (!$con)
      {
      die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
      }
    mysql_select_db("news", $con);
    $news=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM news");
    while($row=mysql_fetch_array($news))
    {
        $date=normal_date($row['date']);
        echo $date;
    }
    mysql_close($con);
}?>
```

Функция для перевода названия месяца с английского на украинский. Не работает.
Никак.

Answer (score 2):

```
$date=normal_date("$row['date']");
```

Во-первых, normal_date() НИЧЕГО не возвращает. 
Во-вторых, двойные кавычки уберите вообще. Они не нужны: вы передаете переменную. Мало того, они существенно все портят, так как в таком случае надо было бы писать

```
"$row[date]"
```

, иначе в функцию передается элемент массива с ключом КАВЫЧКАdateКАВЫЧКА

Answer (score 1):

Ваша функция ничего не возвращает, а только делает echo. Ошибка в этом.
Мне кажется так лучше и очевиднее

```
function normal_date($date){
    $month=array('January'=>'Січня', 'February'=>'Лютого', 'March'=>'Березня');
    return $month[date("F", strtotime($date))];
};
```

Comment: Все равно не работает

Answer (score 1):

```
function ukraineMounth()
{
    $date = date("n");
    $mounth = [
        1 => "Січень",
        2 => "Лютий",
        3 => "Березень",
        4 => "Квітень",
        5 => "Травень",
        6 => "Червень",
        7 => "Липень",
        8 => "Серпень",
        9 => "Вересень",
        10 => "Жовтень",
        11 => "Листопад",
        12 => "Грудень"
    ];

    return $mounth[$date];
}
```

Самый простой вариант..